# How to use mahalanobis distance in cross_validate() python sklearn? error - size of V does not match

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, knn, mahalanobis

How to use mahalanobis distance in cross_validate() python sklearn? i got error because error - size of V does not match. here is my code

```
model=neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,metric="mahalanobis",metric_params={'V': np.cov(X)})
results = cross_validate(estimator=model,X=X,y=y,cv=10,scoring=scoring)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the MahalanobisDistance metric only seems works when n_neighbors is greater than or equal to half the size of your dataset.

The following should run:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

N = 123
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=N)
scoring = "accuracy"
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=(N//2), 
                             metric="mahalanobis", 
                             metric_params={'V': np.cov(X)})
results = cross_validate(estimator=model,X=X,y=y,cv=10,scoring=scoring)
```

Hopefully some one with more knowledge than I can provide us both with a better solution!

Comment: That was not an obvious find. (+1) For a quick fix, you can turn to `brute` instead of the default: `algorithm='ball_tree'`.